# MySQL query for patents citations

Tags: mysql, subquery

I would like to find the citations of all patents under the IPC code G01S, from the international patent database (PATSTAT). The following query returns all patents under G01S.

```
SELECT *
FROM TLS209_APPLN_IPC 
JOIN TLS201_APPLN ON TLS209_APPLN_IPC.APPLN_ID = TLS201_APPLN.APPLN_ID
WHERE TLS209_APPLN_IPC.IPC_CLASS_SYMBOL LIKE "G01S%"
```

Now, I would like to attach the table (TLS212_CITATION) with their patent citations, which includes patent number (PAT_PUBLN_ID)

```
JOIN TLS212_CITATION ON TLS201_APPLN.APPLN_ID = TLS212_CITATION.PAT_PUBLN_ID
```

Unfortunately, this gives me an error. Does anyone have any idea on how to attach the citation table?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you clarify about "this doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: are you placing the last join before your where clause?

Comment: Yes, I place it before the where clause.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: which error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to add the citation table to my query.

```
SELECT *
FROM TLS201_APPLN
JOIN TLS211_PAT_PUBLN ON TLS201_APPLN.APPLN_ID = TLS211_PAT_PUBLN.APPLN_ID 
JOIN TLS212_CITATION ON TLS211_PAT_PUBLN.PAT_PUBLN_ID = TLS212_CITATION.PAT_PUBLN_ID
JOIN TLS209_APPLN_IPC ON TLS201_APPLN.APPLN_ID = TLS209_APPLN_IPC.APPLN_ID
JOIN TLS202_APPLN_TITLE ON TLS201_APPLN.APPLN_ID = TLS202_APPLN_TITLE.APPLN_ID
WHERE TLS209_APPLN_IPC.IPC_CLASS_SYMBOL LIKE "G01S%"
AND TLS201_APPLN.APPLN_AUTH LIKE "US"
AND TLS201_APPLN.EARLIEST_FILING_DATE BETWEEN "19900101" AND "19910101"
```

What I was missing out was that I needed to start with FROM TLS201_APPLN. Also, I needed to join TLS201_APPLN to TLS211_PAT_PUBLN first, and then TLS211_PAT_PUBLN to TLS212_CITATION.

I hope this will be of help to anyone looking for the list of cited patents on PATSTAT.